# SQL Server : many-to-Many Join into Single Row

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I'm relatively new to SQL Server, so bear with me if I'm missing something obvious.

I have a database with tables `Retailers`, `Wholesalers`, and `RetailerWholesaler`.

Currently each retailer can have zero, one, or two wholesalers (but of course that could change with little notice!). I'm having trouble creating a view that has columns for RetailerID, PrimaryWholesalerID, and SecondaryWholesalerID. No matter what I've tried, I keep ending up with Primary/Secondary on separate rows:

```
RetailerID | PrimaryWholesalerID | SecondaryWholesalerID
-----------+---------------------+----------------------
       100 | 8888                | NULL
       100 | NULL                | 9999
```

What I'm trying to get to is:

```
RetailerID | PrimaryWholesalerID | SecondaryWholesalerID
-----------+---------------------+----------------------
       100 | 8888                | 9999
```

And this is the script I currently have:

```
SELECT 
    r.RetailerID,
    CASE WHEN rw.RetailerWholesalerType = 'Primary'
            THEN w.WholesalerID END PrimaryWholesalerID
    CASE WHEN rw.RetailerWholesalerType = 'Secondary'
            THEN w.WholesalerID END SecondaryWholesalerID
FROM
    Retailers r
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    RetailerWholesaler rw ON r.RetailerID = rw.RetailerID
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    Wholesalers w ON rw.WholesalerID = w.WholesalerID
```

I still want to show the `RetailerID` even if there's no primary or secondary wholesaler.

I'm using SQL Server 2017. Thanks in advance for any help or insight.

Comment: What would you do if there were more than one primary or secondary retailers?

Comment: That's why I have it in a separate table rather than two additional column in the `Retailers` table. The way the business operates they currently limit it to two wholesalers, but there's nothing to prevent leadership from changing it to three wholesalers tomorrow (or any other number). I figured a separate table would be most flexible, keeps the relationships simpler, and keeps the database normalized.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can conditionally aggregate the result by using `MAX()`

```
SELECT r.RetailerID,
       MAX(CASE WHEN rw.RetailerWholesalerType = 'Primary'
                THEN w.WholesalerID END) PrimaryWholesalerID
       MAX(CASE WHEN rw.RetailerWholesalerType = 'Secondary'
                THEN w.WholesalerID END) SecondaryWholesalerID
FROM Retailers r
     LEFT OUTER JOIN RetailerWholesaler rw
         ON r.RetailerID = rw.RetailerID
     LEFT OUTER JOIN Wholesalers w
         ON rw.WholesalerID = w.WholesalerID
GROUP BY r.RetailerID
```

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest writing this using aggregation:

```
SELECT r.RetailerID,
       MAX(CASE WHEN rw.RetailerWholesalerType = 'Primary'
                THEN w.WholesalerID
           END) as PrimaryWholesalerID
       MAX(CASE WHEN rw.RetailerWholesalerType = 'Secondary'
                THEN w.WholesalerID
           END) as SecondaryWholesalerID
FROM Retailers r LEFT OUTER JOIN
     RetailerWholesaler rw
     ON r.RetailerID = rw.RetailerID LEFT OUTER JOIN
     Wholesalers w
     ON rw.WholesalerID = w.WholesalerID
GROUP BY r.RetailerID;
```